# I/Process (22926): Sending signal. PID: 22926 SIG: 9 Lost connection to device. while using firebase in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, firebase-authentication

I have created an app which uses firebase auth for authentication.After adding firebase create user. whenever user registers the app crashes giving this error see below.
There is more error then this  i added last few lines here.

```
E/AndroidRuntime(23627):    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:134)
E/AndroidRuntime(23627):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
E/AndroidRuntime(23627):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
E/AndroidRuntime(23627):    ... 16 more
I/Process (23627): Sending signal. PID: 23627 SIG: 9
Lost connection to device.
Exited (sigterm)
```

> This is my code
>   register_screen.dart

```
class RegisterScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  static const String id = 'register_screen';

  @override
  _RegisterScreenState createState() => _RegisterScreenState();
}

class _RegisterScreenState extends State<RegisterScreen> {
  final _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

  final TextEditingController _emailTextController = TextEditingController();
  final TextEditingController _passwordTextController = TextEditingController();
  String emailText;
  String passwordText;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
        children: <Widget>[
          Icon(
            Icons.apps,
            size: 50.0,
          ),

          Padding(
            padding:
                const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 40.0, vertical: 20.0),
            child: Container(
              decoration:
                  BoxDecoration(color: Color(kFloatingActionButtonColor)),
              child: FlatButton(
                onPressed: () async {
                  try {
                    final newUser = await _auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
                        email: emailText, password: passwordText);
                    if (newUser != null) {
                      Navigator.pushNamed(context, HomeScreen.id);
                    }
                  } catch (e) {
                    print(e);
                  }
                },
                child: Text(
                  'REGISTER',
                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 20.0),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I have no idea how to fix them any help would be great.